# Not receiving emails from Steam. Email host and Steam both confirm that emails are successfully being delivered

Tags: email, dns, steam

On 2023-11-05 I changed my domain registrar from Google Domains to NameSilo and my email host from Google Workspace to Purelymail (I wanted to save some cash and don't do that much emailing and trying to generally de-Google). I setup everything and didn't notice any issues. I updated email accounts in a bunch of places with no problems, but then hit a snag when I tried to update my Steam account. I'm not receiving any emails from Steam on my new host through my domain.

- I have no issues with incoming/outgoing emails except with Steam to my domain.
- I reached out to both my host support and Steam support and they confirmed emails are being delivered.
- I don't see any emails from Steam to my domain.
- When I use tools/sites to check my DNS records (like dig, nslookup, nslookup.io) I see all my records **except** CNAME records. In this case my CNAME records are DKIM and DMARC records.
- When I entered the values for the CNAME records (provided by my email host) they were rejected because the provided values had a period on the end. I removed the period and the records saved without issue. (I don't know if this actually has any impact. I don't know enough about DNS.)
- I eventually changed my Steam email account to my email account through my host (not pointed at my domain) and the confirmation mail came through instantly.
- I don't see anything in any sort of junk/spam/trash folder.
- I don't know if this is a DNS issue. It's the one thing I've found any sort of weirdness with.

Edit to follow up questions:

- I'm using CNAME for the DKIM/DMARC records because I'm following directions from the email host. I did read when searching that DKIM are usually TXT records, but that sometimes they are provided as CNAME which acts as a pointer to the actual DKIM value that the host can manage instead of providing the value directly to the user.

digs of CNAME and MX (replaced my actual domain with MYDOMAIN.com)

---

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> MYDOMAIN.com CNAME
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12739
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;MYDOMAIN.com.          IN  CNAME

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
MYDOMAIN.com.       10800   IN  SOA ns1.dnsowl.com. hostmaster.dnsowl.com. 1699857886 7200 1800 1209600 600

;; Query time: 188 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov 13 00:46:51 CST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 99
```

---

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> purelymail.com MX
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42800
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;purelymail.com.            IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
purelymail.com.     86400   IN  MX  50 mailserver.purelymail.com.

;; Query time: 16 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov 13 00:54:24 CST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 70
```

---

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> MYDOMAIN.com MX
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9506
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;MYDOMAIN.com.          IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
MYDOMAIN.com.       7207    IN  MX  50 mailserver.purelymail.com.

;; Query time: 200 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov 13 00:54:38 CST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 79
```

Comment: What _do_ you see in dig/nslookup for the DKIM/DMARC records? And... why are those CNAME records? They are not supposed to be CNAME records. (That being said, _all_ CNAME values internally have a period at the end; if your new DNS control panel is rejecting a trailing period in CNAMEs, that's just _odd._) This will have nothing to do with receiving mail – both DKIM and DMARC are only about mail going _from_ your domain – but it's weird and probably worth looking into.

Comment: Overall it doesn't sound like a DNS issue because the mail _does_ reach your provider, but what do you see when querying the `MX` records at the root domain?

Comment: Steam support might help you change the email address registered to your steam account. You'll need to provide them with some info for authentication purposes, like a number of digits from your bank account number or a transaction number so they can confirm you are the owner  https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/135514823817032564/

Comment: @u1686_grawity Added additional info about CNAME and MX. I'm glad that the DKIM and DMARC won't impact incoming mail (my nearly sole use of personal email). Thank you for confirming the CNAME weirdness. My hope, and something I'll follow up on separately, is that since all CNAME values have a period at the end that they simply add it on for the user implicitly (even though that creates user experience weirdness).

Comment: @Gantendo Yes. Thank you for pointing that out. They actually already offered to do that. I declined however because I'm concerned about having my account pointed at an address that won't receive their mail. At this point I'm mostly annoyed/intrigued by the situation and am really hoping to find an answer.

Comment: @AdrianBurd Life is just a series of workarounds waiting for a fix.

Comment: At protocol level, all DNS names end with an empty label (e.g. `google.com.` as in {`"google"`, `"com"`, `""`}). In typical usage this is omitted, but in DNS zonefiles the trailing period indicates "this is an absolute name" as opposed to "this name should have the base domain appended to it (e.g. `www CNAME serv01`). The behavior varies across the various web-based control panels, but most of them treat both dotted and dotless variants the same way; it's extremely weird to outright reject a trailing dot.